# AWS Network Load Balancer: why would an Internal NLB have a public DNS name?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I created an Internal Network Load Balancer:
[image]

What is the point of having a DNS name with an internal NLB?

Plus, I've tried to curl the DNS name, there is no response anyways.

Why have it in the first place?

Comment: The DNS name works inside the VPC network. DNS isn't just for the Internet, it can work on any network.

Comment: @MarkB  This is the type of knowledge that is so trivial once someone points it out, but very hard to get from just searching on internet.  Of course this is very basic computer networks knowledge, but I did not have a solid foundation of basics. If you could write it as an answer, which I will accept as the correct answer, it may help someone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DNS name works inside the VPC network. DNS isn't just for the Internet, it can work on any network.

Answer (score -1):

I understand the answer, but it's unsatisfactory.

Seemingly if you create an internal NLB, it should at least be an option to associate that NLB domain name with a private hosted zone.

While minor, DNS names and their associated IP's **do** leak network structure. Perhaps, minor but it is an OPSEC concern.

Here are the docs on the issue - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-internal-load-balancers.html